# Pull data from sqlite3 table

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to pull data from a specific row when the user tries to make two or more entries on the same date(date being the primary key).

In my .h file

```
@interface PunchClock : UIViewController{

    sqlite3 *db;

}
-(NSString *) filePath;
-(void)openDB;
-(void) createTable: (NSString *) tableName
         withField1:(NSString *) field1
         withField2:(NSString *) field2
         withField3:(NSString *) field3;
```

In my .m file (not sure if any of the follow code is needed for deciphering my problem, but ill post it anyways)

```
-(void) createTable: (NSString *) tableName
         withField1:(NSString *) field1
         withField2:(NSString *) field2
         withField3:(NSString *) field3;
{
    char *err;
    NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@'('%@' TEXT PRIMARY KEY,'%@' TEXT,'%@' TEXT);",tableName,field1,field2,field3];

    if(sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not create table");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"table created");
    }
}



-(NSString *) filePath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PunchClock.sql"];

    return path;
}

-(void)openDB{
    if(sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}
```

Now here is where my problem is. I can successfully insert data BUT when the user inputs data on the same date(field 1 being date , my primary key) I want to pull that data out update it and update the table. Im stuck at the part where I pull the data from the row(check comments for clarification):

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
{
        NSString *HoursWorked = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", final];
        NSString *TotalEarned = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", paidFloat];

        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO HourLog ('Date', 'HoursWorked','TotalEarned') VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@')", dbDate , HoursWorked, TotalEarned];

        char *err;
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_close(db);
           // NSAssert(0,@"Could not update table");

            //primary key already exists

            [self openDB];
            NSString *currentHoursWorked = HoursWorked;
            NSString *currentTotalEarned = TotalEarned;
            NSString *previousHoursWorked;
            NSString *previousTotalEarned;


            NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT FROM HourLog WHERE Date = '%@'", dbDate];

            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            // the if statement below is not being executed for some reason? Can someone see why?
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK){

                char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
                NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];
                previousHoursWorked = field2Str;

                char *field3 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
                NSString *field3Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field3];
                previousTotalEarned = field3Str;

            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);

           sqlite3_close(db);

            NSLog(@"%@", previousHoursWorked); 
            NSLog(@"%@", previousTotalEarned);



        }else{
            NSLog(@"table updated");

        }

    }





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You're not logging `sqlite3_errmsg` if your `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed, and I would have thought it would, as you don't specify what fields to return from your `SELECT` statement.

   Whenever you have a SQLite error, you should make sure you're logging `sqlite3_errmsg`.
2. You also never invoke `sqlite3_step` to actually perform the `SELECT` statement.
3. Finally, `sqlite3_column_text` returns 0-based index, not 1-based index, so the first column is `0` and the second one is `1`. As [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) say, "The leftmost column of the result set has the index 0."

So, I would have thought that you'd want something like:

```
// replace column_a and column_b with your column names

NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT column_a, column_b FROM HourLog WHERE Date = '%@'", dbDate];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){

    int rc;
    if ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];
        previousHoursWorked = field2Str;

        char *field3 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        NSString *field3Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field3];
        previousTotalEarned = field3Str;
    } else if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog("%s: sqlite3_step failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }    
} else {
    NSLog("%s: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
```

---

By the way, while you can do this `SELECT` first to see if there's a match and do an `UPDATE` if you find one, and do an `INSERT` if not, it might just be easier to use the SQLite `INSERT OR REPLACE` syntax. See the `INSERT` [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).