# Rows not updating sqlite3

Tags: ios, sqlite

The following code is suppose to update 2 columns (HoursWorked and TotalEarned) in the row where Date(Primary Key) = todays date which is stored in the string dbDate. I think my update string might be written wrong. The alert view is being triggered.

```
        sqlite3_stmt *newstatement;
        sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE HourLog SET HoursWorked = '%@', TotalEarned = '%@' WHERE Date ='%@'", HoursWorked, TotalEarned, dbDate];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &newstatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK){

            NSLog(@"details updated");

            UIAlertView *alertDialog;
            alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Title"
                           message:@"Details Updated!"
                           delegate:nil
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                           otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertDialog show];
            sqlite3_step(newstatement);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(newstatement);
        sqlite3_close(db);
```

Comment: You should only call `sqlite3_step` if the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds.

Comment: You should check out Core Data or a similar open-source library. I'm sure you'll find either very helpful. :)

Comment: BTW - It is the call to `sqlite3_step` that actually executes the query.

Comment: What is the data type of `dbDate`? `NSString` or `NSDate`? It needs to be in the right format to match your `Date` column in the database.

Comment: NSString. Also sqlite3_step is executed anyways as I dont have a else statement to my if for error handling as I know I should but just dealing with this problem first. But yes your correct it should be within my if statement only if succussfully updated. I made the changes to my code within my question.

Comment: I'd also be interested if you're trying to write to the app bundle...

Comment: @H2CO3 As always, that's an excellent suggestion. I happened to know that from his [prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827046/pull-data-from-sqlite3-table) that he was opening it from the Documents folder, but you're right that the accidental opening of database in bundle is a common source of database updates not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. The `UPDATE` syntax is not correct. The individual fields being updated must be separated by a comma, not the word `AND`.
2. You probably shouldn't report that the update succeeded until you confirmed the result of `sqlite3_step`.
3. In case you're not getting a hit on your `WHERE` clause, I might suggest determining how many rows were updated, so you can confirm that the `WHERE` clause succeeded.
4. And, [as always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827046/pull-data-from-sqlite3-table), report `sqlite3_errmsg` if your SQLite calls fail or else you're flying blind.

Thus:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

int originalTotalCount = sqlite3_total_changes(db);

NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE HourLog SET HoursWorked = %@ , TotalEarned = %@ WHERE Date='%@'", HoursWorked, TotalEarned, dbDate];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
} else {
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"%s: step failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    } else {
        int rowsUpdated = sqlite3_total_changes(db) - originalTotalCount;

        NSString *message;

        if (rowsUpdated == 1)
            message = @"Updated one row";
        else if (rowsUpdated == 0)
            message = @"No rows updated";
        else
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Updated %d rows", rowsUpdated]; // should never happen

        NSLog(@"%@", message);

        UIAlertView *alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                              message:message
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertDialog show];
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

I personally wouldn't use the single quotes around the numeric values for `HoursWorked` and `TotalEarned`. And you might consider storing the date in one of the established [SQLite date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: I used your code and also tried removing the single quotes and still doesn't work. The dbDate string is already formatted to how i'd like.

Comment: It says updated one row. So it looks like its successfully working but the update isn't saved?

Comment: YES :) Thank you so much for your help and patience! My gut feeling was that statement from the beginning. Again Thank you!